# java how to debug drag and drop?

Tags: java, debugging, drag-and-drop, jdeveloper

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question.  If not, please advise which forum I can post the question.

I am new to drag and drop, and want to debug the samples to learn.  After I set a few breakpoints, and tried to drag and drop, the IDE hangs.  Looks like it enters a deadlock. I am using JDeveloper.

Is it a common issue?  If so, how to work around it?

Comment: Almost all IDE's which allow you to debug your code will permit you to set a code line breakpoint. When the code is run through the IDE in debug mode the code will stop and highlight the breakpoint line. You can then step through the code one line at a time until all its processing is complete. If there is a hang (a lot of times from a while/loop because the condition to exit it is never met) then you will see it as you step through the code. Read the documentation for your particular IDE with regards to Debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working, and wanted to share.

It appears that debugger and debuggee need to be in different displays in order to debug drag and drop.